# Is it possible for a Tomcat Web Application , to write a file outside the server?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, file-permissions

I have a tomcat web application.Is it possible to create a folder / write files outside the server(.../web)...

For example to write some data to /home/desktop.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But remember the Security Manager and write permission on your directory.